# Is there any way to access static global variable defined in main.c and modify it in another file?

Tags: c, static, extern

For example:

In `main.c`

```
static glob_var;
```

I want to modify the value of glob_var in another file say `file1.c`

Comment: "static global" doesn't make sense. Make up your mind about what the variable is for. The presence of (non-static) globals is almost always spaghetti programming and bad design.

Comment: Write a setter function in `main.c` that modifies that variable and call this function from `file1.c`.

Comment: If you can access a pointer to the variable, you can access the variable by dereferencing the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Making an variable `static` makes its identifier inaccessible from other translation unit (what usually means other C-file). You can either

1. Make the variable non-static.

```
//main.c

int glob_var;


//file1.c

extern int glob_var;
```

Note that the declaration should be put to a header file.

2. Keep it static and add a helper function for access.

```
//main.c

static int glob_var;
void SetGlobVar(int val) {
  glob_var = val;
}


//file1.c

void SetGlobVar(int);
void foo(void) {
  SetGlobVar(42);
}
```

Note that the declaration of `SetGlobVar()` should be put to a header file.

Answer (score 0):

The comments and other answer address the question of how to *access and modify a* **static** *global"*.  The following is offed as an alternative to using  *static* for this purpose...

When needing to create a variable that is global and can be changed among several translation units I believe it is more idiomatic to use the [`extern`storage class](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_storage_classes.htm).   This is typically done by:

- *Declaring* the extern variable in a header file
- *Defining* the extern variable one-time-only in a .c file that `#includes`s the header file.
- *Access and modify* the extern class variable from any translation unit that `#include`s the header file in which the `extern` is declared.

Example:

in `some.h`:

```
void modify_glob_var(int val);
...
extern int glob_var;//declare extern variable
```

in `main.c`

```
#include "some.h"
...
int glob_var = 0;// define extern variable
...
modify_glob_var(10);//access and modify extern variable
```

in `some_other.c`

```
include "some.h"
...
void modify_glob_var(int val)
{
    glob_var = val;//value of extern glob_var is changed here
}
```